# Adding subviews on UIWindow covers the keyboard called by textfields

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8

I am trying to imitate an alert view and i show a view with two text fields above a view with a translucent background. The problem is that when i try to tap on the text fields , the keyboard is shown behind my translucent view and i can't tap it no more. Is there a solution?

Here is my code:

```
 if (_grayView==nil) {
    _grayView = [[UIView alloc]init];
    _grayView.frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds];
    _grayView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    _grayView.alpha  = 0.7;
    [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] lastObject] addSubview:_grayView];

}
//Show the dimensions view when choosing an image
_dimensionsView.hidden = NO;
[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] lastObject] addSubview:_dimensionsView];
```

In the _dimensionsView i have the textfileds.

Comment: There is not enough information in your question. Where is the code calling the keyboard? Where are your UIGestureRecoginizers assigned?

Comment: Why aren't you just presenting a modal view controller?

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing isn't a very good idea to begin with.  Also be aware that you can't count on `windows.lastObject` to always be the window you expect.  iOS 7 and 8 are more and more liberal with creating new windows for keyboards and modals.  You might not be adding your subview to the window you're expecting.